# Regular Expression don't include Zero-Width assertions in match groups

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have updated the following re to not match when the string is B/C, B/O, S/C, or S/O.

old `(.*)/(.*)`

new: `(.*)(?<!^(B|S)(?=/(C|O)$))/(.*)`

This regex is being used downstream with a list of other regex patterns and is expected to separate the data into two groups. Is there a way for my regex pattern (or a better one) to not count the zero-width assertions?

I've tried pushing the validation till the end with a single lookbehind assertion but that only has access to the group after the slash.

I've also tried enclosing the assertions in `(?:...)` but inner parenthesis are still counted towards matching groups.

Comment: If you don't want `(B|S)` to be a capturing group, don't *use* a capturing group.

Comment: What's my alternative? If I strip the parenthesis, the positive lookahead is associated with only the S [link] (https://regex101.com/r/Xztp5e/2) Edit: I guess I can repeat the positive lookahead as so: `(.*)(?<!^B(?=/C$|/O$)|^S(?=/C$|/O$))/(.*)`

Comment: What do you think `(?:...)` means?

Comment: ahhh! thanks for the help @user2357112

Comment: Secondly, for the future, try to include your input and expected output in your questions. It helps those who answer to know precisely what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user2357112

`(.*)(?<!^(?:B|S)(?=/(?:C|O)$))/(.*)`

I was using `(?:...)` incorrectly on my first attempts